# The right shift operator in $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(e_k)$ be a total orthonormal sequence in a separable Hilbert space $H$ and we define the right shift operator to be the linear operator $T\colon H\to H$ such that $Te_k=e_{k+1}$.

Who is in the case of $\ell^2$ the right shift operator? It seems natural to me that it is

$$T\colon \ell^2\to\ell^2\quad (\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots)\mapsto(0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots).\tag1$$ I would like to see this formally, so let's proceed as follows. Let $(e_k)$, where $e_k=(\delta_{kj})_{j=1}^\infty$, we knwon that this is an orthonormal sequence in $\ell^2$. Let $x=(\xi_j)\in \ell^2$, then $$x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle x , e_k\rangle e_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_ke_k.$$

Note that $$\langle x, e_k\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \xi_j\overline{\delta_{kj}}=\xi_k.$$

Now,

$$Tx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle x, e_k\rangle e_{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_ke_{k+1}.$$

> I can't see definition $(1)$ from this though. Could someone please explain to me if from what I've done I should see $(1)$?

**My Solution after comments.**
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\xi_k e_{k+1}=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\xi_ke_{k+1} \\   &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\xi_k\cdot (0,0,0,\dots, 1, 0,\dots)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[(0,\xi_1,0,\dots)+(0,0,\xi_2,0,\dots)+\cdots + (0,\dots,0,\xi_n,0,\dots)\right]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[(0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots, \xi_n,0,\dots)\right].
\end{align}
Let $y_n:=(0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots, \xi_n,0,\cdots,)$ and $y=(0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots, \xi_n,\dots)$. Then we have that $$\lVert y-y_n\rVert_{\ell^2}^2=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \lvert \xi_k \rvert^2<\infty$$ since is the remainder of a convergent series. It's correct?

Comment: Did you try to prove that the series you got converges to $(0, \xi_1, \xi_2,...)$? This is pretty straightforward.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_ke_{k+1}=\xi_1e_2+\xi_2e_3+\dots=$
$(0,\xi_1,0,0,\dots)+(0,0,\xi_2,0,\dots)+\dots$

Comment: @AnneBauval That's not really a proof though. It needs to be shown that this sum indeed converges to the vector $(0,\xi_1,\xi_2,...)$ specifically in the $\ell^2$ norm. In some other norms the sum would not have a limit at all.

Comment: Of course @Mark but I think that's the only thing the OP missed. We all now (and the OP used it) that $\forall a=(a_k)\in\ell^2,$ $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_ke_k$ converges in $\ell^2$ to $a.$

Comment: @MarkThank you. I used your comments to propose a solution. Does it seem correct to you?